# specific javascript per view Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

**I'm trying that not all the javascripts are used in all the htmls.**

The first thing i did was delete the require_tree.

Then i used this line in my view

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "fiscal", "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>
```

but i got this error.

```
Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( judicial.js ) to 'config/initializers/assets.rb' and restart your server
```

Then i did it, **i installed something called yarn** and ran this in console

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and i got this.

```
yarn install v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
info Lockfile not saved, no dependencies.
Done in 0.12s.
```

But still the same error.

**Please I, need to know where is the mistake or an alternative.**

Comment: And did you restart your server after editing `config/initializers/assets.rb`?

Comment: i thought i did but no, it´s necesary run rails restart. Thanks

Comment: If asking then yes, it's necessary after any change to that file.